# Plot integration curve of a system of ODEs

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm really n00b in *Mathematica*, so please bear with me, as this seems to be my only option to learn how to do what I wany to do.

I have a system of two differential equations:

```
y' = v[t]
v'[t] = -a^2y
```

Now, assuming I know the solution of this system is: $y = cos(a\,t),\ v = -a\,sin(a\,t)$, I want to plot the integral curve of the two, on the v-y surface, with `a t` getting values from 0 to `2 π`.

I've tried various combinations of `StreamPlot`, `VectorPlot` and many other functions, without any success, although I think it's suppose to be really simple. I've tried also to make a plot in 3D with `VectorPlot3D`, but to no avail.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: You are wrong. There is a good way to learn more apart from only asking questions. Here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice you will find lots of resources to learn Mathematica. Have fun!

Comment: Besides, this: `a^2y`is an error. Mma reads it as "a to the power of `2y`", while you evidently mean "`a` squared times `y`. You should have written `a^2*y`.  Finally, have a look into Menu/Help/Documentation Center/NDSolve/BasicExamples/System of ordinary differential equations. You will find there the answer to the analogous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way, if I understand you right (even though I think this will be closed :)

```
Clear[v, t, y];
a = 9;
eq1 = y'[t] == v[t];
eq2 = v'[t] == -a^2  y[t];
sol = First@DSolve[{eq1, eq2, y[0] == 1, v[0] == 2}, {v[t], y[t]}, t];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@{v[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(as others mentioned, you have lots of syntax errors there)

Comment: Thanks, this is really what I wanted, with small addition - I want to plot it as vector (with direction) and that's why I've tried to do it with VectorPlot. As for the `syntax errors` - and this goes to Alexei as well - I didn't intended to write the accurate syntax here, this was only to explain the problem. Of course in Mathematice I used the correct syntax.

Comment: Maybe you want to see something like StreamPlot[{-y, x}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}] ?

Comment: Not exactly. I want the result to be just like Nasser did, but with arrows along the curve, showing the 'direction' of the curve.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of explaining too much, here is some correct MMA-code for your problem. By studying it (and the documentation of MMA) in detail you will discover the answer to your question:

```
Clear[a, y, v, yy, vv, sol]

sol = 
  DSolve[{y'[t] == v[t] , v'[t] == -a^2 y[t], y[0] == 0, v[0] == 1}, {y[t], v[t]}, t];

{yy[t_, a_], vv[t_, a_]} = {y[t], v[t]} /. sol[[1]]

(* Out[71]= {Sin[a t]/a, Cos[a t]} *)

With[{a = 2},
 ParametricPlot[{yy[t, a], vv[t, a]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]/a}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

I have dropped the image here for simplicity.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Please do not include the In[] and Out[] in the code, as it makes it hard to copy/paste as is.

Comment: Ok Nasser, thanks for your hint.

Comment: @Nasser Ins and Outs removed

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for upvoting. Actually, you should have punished me because I did it so late ;-)